# How to redirect URL Friendly created with rewrite

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, seo, url-rewriting

I created URL with rewrite mod.

This is the command:
RewriteRule ^productos/(.+)-(.+).html ecommerce/buscador.php?categoria=$2

Example the URL
http://www.frutasadomicilio.cl/productos/Verduras-2.html

The URL works good but now i need change the URL. I am thinking that with redirect 301 is my way  an a solution. But when i try the redirect the URL, the command return the new url but with parameter.

The command is:
redirect 301  /productos/Verduras-2.html /productos/Verduras_a_domicilio-2.html

when I access the URL from google search,  the Browser return this URL with parameter
http://www.frutasadomicilio.cl/productos/Verduras_a_domicilio-2.html?categoria=2

Any suggestion?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Do not mix `Redirect` and `RewriteRule` for similar URLs. I suggest you to use only `RewriteRule` as

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^productos/Verduras-2\.html$ /productos/Verduras_a_domicilio-2.html [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^productos/(.+)-(.+)\.html$ ecommerce/buscador.php?categoria=$2 [NC,L]
```

Also, the order of the rules above is important.